# Changing subscription plans and billing the difference

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to implement seat based pricing but the documentation doesn't cover scenarios for changing plan mid subscription.

For reference these are the docs I am following: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/

Let me give you an example.  Lets say I have this pricing:

- 1-10 seats $5 each per month
- 11+ seats $3 each per month
- To mimic this in PayPal I create 2 quantity based subscription plans.  One with a quantity price of $5, the other for $3.  Both plans are on the same product and have term set to monthly.

There are a few situations I am unsure how to handle and cannot find this information in the docs.  They are as follows:

1) User signs up for 1 seat on the 1st June.  On the 15th June they decide to change to 5 seats.  The docs say this will be adjusted in the "next billing cycle" but I am unclear what that means.  Their next billing cycle is in 15 days so does that mean they get access to 4 seats for free that month?  What I would want to happen is the difference is calculated.  The user has paid $5 so far and is halfway through the month so half a month cost is $2.50.  The new subscription price is $25.  So the remainder of the month would cost $12.50.  So the difference to pay is $10 to cover them to the end of the month with the additional seats until they will then be billed $25 for a full month.  Is this in anyway possible?

2) User signs ups for 5 seats.  They then upgrade to 20 seats halfway through the month which moves them onto a different plan to get discounted pricing.  How does situation 1 play out again in this regard when changing plans?  How are the differences calculated and billed?

It seems in the old billings API you could override the setup cost when creating the subscription but that no longer seems possible.  It is not possible to add the setup cost to a plan because this needs to be added dynamically based on the elapsed time in billing cycle, change in seat quantity and change in plan cost.

Have PayPal really removed all possible ways of dealing with package upgrades?

Answer (score 0):

To have new arbitrary costs, setup or otherwise, you would need to dynamically create a bespoke package/plan for that particular checkout.

Comment: I would end up with thousands of plans because I would be creating them for each billing change.  That would make managing standard plans from on the fly plans very difficult.  Is that really the only way to do it?  Also managing price changes would be impossible doing it in that manner.